# Cierre la pestaña del navegador actual al hacer clic en el botón, usando reactjs

Tags: reactjs

¿Hay alguna manera de cerrar la pestaña del navegador actual presionando el botón, usando reactjs?

Lo he intentado window.close() y self.close() ninguno de los métodos de JavaScript parece funcionar. No quiero el evento de cerrar ventana en React. Quiero cerrar la pestaña del navegador. window.close()solo se puede usar cuando window.open() se usa.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta final es sin abrir una pestaña, no puede cerrarla usando window.close (). He buscado por todas partes, así que se me ocurrió un truco. si está usando reactjs hooks, simplemente abra la misma URL en la misma pestaña usando useEffect como este-

```
useEffect(() => {
window.open("https://xyz.abc/", "_self", "");
console.log("open window");
}, []);
```

Luego haga la función de cerrar y agregue onclick para cerrar () que tiene window.close();

¡Esto definitivamente funcionará! Tratado y probado.